# Using Golang's SSH package to act as a server -- how do I write to stdout?

Tags: go, ssh

I'm using Go's [ssh](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) package to act an as SSH server, and I wanted to write some tests for that code with an SSH client implemented with the same package.

In the server-side code, I write stdout data to the ssh [channel](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Channel) using `channel.Write()` and stderr data using `channel.Stderr().Write()`, like so:

```golang
// sample of server code
switch data.Type {
case "stdout":
    channel.Write([]byte("stdout message!"))
case "stderr":
    channel.Stderr().Write([]byte("stderr message!"))
}
```

In the client-side code, I read this data like so:

```golang
// sample of client code
conn, _ := gossh.Dial("tcp", "localhost:2222", config)
defer conn.Close()

session, _ := conn.NewSession()
defer session.Close()

stData := make([]byte, 100)
stderr, _ := session.StderrPipe()
stderr.Read(b)

stdout, _ := session.StdoutPipe()
stdoutData := make([]byte, 100)
stdout.Read(stdoutData)
```

This works fine when the code is actually running and communicating with a local ssh process. **The problem** is that when I'm the client, my read from the `StderrPipe` works as expected, but my read from `StdoutPipe` simply hangs. It appears that calls to `channel.Write()` send data somewhere other than the `StdoutPipe`, so my question is simply: where does that data go?

Comment: You're not concurrently reading from both streams. Are you certain you have actually written to the `Channel`, and have reached the read from stdout?

Comment: Based on log output, I am certain the write is succeeding from the server's point of view, and the client is reaching the line that reads from `stdout`. Do you think I'd be better off wrapping these reads in a `for` loop within a goroutine? (that is the approach I take in a separate client implementation that is talking to an "actual" SSH server)

Comment: Yes, it's a given that you will need a for loop _somewhere_ (which could be inside a `ReadAll` or `Copy` call), because you are reading from a stream. You should also be doing this concurrently, because either stream will block the other, i.e. you can't read from stdout unless stderr was closed or had some data to read.

Comment: Huh! That worked (thank you!), but I don't really understand why. In the above example, let's say I comment out everything to do with stdout; I'm able to read from `stderr` outside of a loop. However the reverse is not true of `stdout`, i.e. even if that's the only pipe I set up and the only write I perform as the server. I don't know why there's a discrepancy between those two behaviors

Answer (score 0):

For reasons I still don't completely understand, it appears that JimB is correct and the key here is to set up goroutines that continuously read from stdout and stderr. I ended up doing something like this:

```golang
// provide pipes for two-way communication with the server
func setupIo(session *ssh.Session) (io.WriteCloser, chan []byte, chan []byte) {
    stdout, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())
    stderr, err := session.StderrPipe()
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())
    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    Expect(err).To(BeNil())

    stdoutChan := make(chan []byte)
    stderrChan := make(chan []byte)

    go readPipe(stdout, stdoutChan)
    go readPipe(stderr, stderrChan)

    return stdin, stdoutChan, stderrChan
}

func readPipe(pipe io.Reader, outputChan chan []byte) {
    b := make([]byte, 100)
    for {
        if n, err := pipe.Read(b); err != nil {
            return
        } else if n > 0 {
            outputChan <- b[:n]
        }
    }
}

// later in the test...
_, stdoutChan, _ := setupIo(session)
output := <-stderrChan
// make assertions about output
// ...
```